# Get attr form <a href>

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

ive got a problem with getting attr from `<a href>`.

Got something likte this

```
<a href="#callback" realurl="callback.aspx">Callback</a>
```

And jQuery

```
$('#callback').bind('pageAnimationEnd', function (e, info) {

                var realurl = $(this).attr('realurl');

                if (!$(this).data('loaded')) {
                    $(this).append($('<table border=0 width="100%" height="100%"><tr width="100%" height="100%"><td>Wczytuję...</td></tr></table>').
                        load(realurl, function () {
                            $(this).parent().data('loaded', true);
                            $('#ParentTest').html("test");
                        }));
                }
            });
```

And im getting all the time undefined from $(this).attr('realurl').

Comment: your anchor does not have an id specified and will not be matched by that selector. what is `$(this)` here?

Comment: Cfaniak, was this answer useful? If so, could you please accept it (click the checkmark)

Answer (score 9):

This does not work the way you intend.

```
$('#callback')
```

finds the elements having `id="callback"`. So if your HTML would be like:

```
<a id="callback" href="#callback" realurl="callback.aspx">Callback</a>
```

it would work.
Alternatively, you can leave the html as is and write:

```
$("a[@href='#callback']")
```

instead. This should get all `a` elements having the `href` attribute set to `#callback`

Comment: typo: s/""#callback"/"callback"/

Comment: mm? Boldewyn, which occurrence is that? I think all #callback should like that? TIA, roland